# EvoPdf convert large Html table use too much RAM

Tags: evopdf

I have a Html file which is roughly 4.3MB contains a table with 6 columns and 10k rows. Each cell contains 1-10 characters, has only "class" attribute for its style which is very simple (font family, font size, text color and cell color).

I converted this file to Pdf but EvoPdf used almost 11GB RAM (I built my project to run on 64bit) and crashed my IIS but didn't return any result. I tried with fewer row (5k) and EvoPdf did return result but still use a lot memory. And the result is almost 150MB.

I don't know I did anything wrong there.
And for my settings, I use repeat table header and embed font.
Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: You can contact evopdf support and provide the HTML document with CSS for analysis.

Comment: I find that using overflow: hidden on table cell create huge memory leak, and I have that CSS on every cell

Comment: DungTran, did you contact @EvoPdf and what is the solution? Could you post an answer?